# Getting duplicate values when selecting data from two different tables while also overwriting different records

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently struggling with this problem. I am being asked to figure out what physician has not treated patient #3249. I have figured out how to get to the point where I can pull just the physician_id for the doctor that didn't treat the patient. My problem is that when I try to pull the doctor's name from a different table, not only does the physician_id duplicate but the doctor's name gets replaced with the other doctor's name as well.

Here is how I created and linked the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE pt_treatment (     patient_no NUMBER(4),   physician_id NUMBER(4),     item_code NUMBER(3),    num_times_serviced NUMBER(3), 
CONSTRAINT pt_treatment_pk PRIMARY KEY (patient_no, physician_id, item_code),
CONSTRAINT pt_treatement_patient_no_fk FOREIGN KEY (patient_no) REFERENCES patient (patient_no),
CONSTRAINT pt_treatment_physician_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (physician_id) REFERENCES doctor (physician_id),
CONSTRAINT pt_treatment_item_code_fk FOREIGN KEY (item_code) REFERENCES item (item_code));
```

And DOCTOR TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE doctor (
    physician_id NUMBER(4),
    doctor_name VARCHAR2(30),
    doctor_phone VARCHAR2(12),
CONSTRAINT doctor_physician_id_PK PRIMARY KEY (physician_id))
```

;

Here is my statement for selecting the data:

```
SELECT distinct pt.physician_id, d.doctor_name
    FROM pt_treatment pt, doctor d
    WHERE pt.physician_id NOT IN (select physician_id FROM pt_treatment WHERE patient_no = 3249);
```

This shows my output in mySQL: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1NIP.png)
The first part shows my doctors table and how the two doctors line up with different ID's
The second part shows the pt_treatment table output; notice how there the only physician_id that lines up with patient_no 3249 is 4321.
Finally, the last bit shows my output and how the physician_id got printed twice with both doctor's names.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT distinct d.physician_id, d.doctor_name, pt.patient_no
FROM doctor d
LEFT JOIN pt_treatment pt ON d.physician_id = pt.physician_id and pt.patient_no=3249
WHERE pt.patient_no IS NULL
/*THE doctors who have not treated patient 3249 will have patient_id null*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are not specifying join condition, hence cross join is happening between the two tables.

You need to apply the outer join in order to get the details of such doctor. Try the below query:

```
SELECT distinct d.physician_id, d.doctor_name
FROM pt_treatment pt left outer join doctor d
on pt.physician_id=d.physician_id where pt.patient_no =3249 and pt.physician_id is null;
```

Comment: Thank you! So an outer join just joins the two tables by the phyisican_id instead of by both columns?

Comment: You can read about joins at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp